# Wordpress registration page template

Tags: login, forms, user-registration

I'm very new in wordpress, and I have a client that needs a custom registration/login form on the front-end side. I also need custom user fields. (phone, company name, about, blog url, etc).

For the custom fields I found the `add_user_meta` function on Wordpress Codex, but I didn't find any information about the custom registration/login page templates.

I finished my first Wordpress template, so I have idea how does it work, but I don't know where to start this registration/login thing.

p.s. I would like to do this without plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has no default form or way to create custom registration and login pages. However, it is quite possible to do all this yourself! I'll try to get you started:

### 1. Page Templates

WordPress offers something called [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates). You can add a file (e.g. `tpl-my-template.php` to your theme and add

```
/*
Template Name: My Template
*/
```

at the start of the file. Now, when you create a page in the admin panel, the "Page Attributes" box on the right allows you to select this template. When a page with "My Template" as the template is displayed, it will use the file `tpl-my-template.php`.

You could create page templates for the login page and for the registration page, so you can add your forms and custom logic to the page via the page templates.

### 2. Adding the form

Next, you can add the registration form (or login form) with any fields you like. For security, you should add a hidden [nonce field](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) to this form.

### 3. Handling the form

WordPress is event-driven. It allows you to "hook into" [actions and filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API). You should do the same when checking your form. Try hooking into the `init` action, which is basically fired after most basic setup is completed but no output has been generated yet.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse152106_handle_registration' );

function wpse152106_handle_registration() {
    // Handle registration form
}
```

### 3.a Registration

To add a new user to an installation, you can use [`wp_insert_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user), combined with [`add_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) for your custom fields.

### 3.b Logging in

You can log in using [`wp_signon`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon), which also does error checking for you, returning a [`WP_Error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) object on failure.

I hope I've given you a few waypoints in tackling this problem!